# Strategies for DRY when using ViewModels instead of Entities

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

A lot of our pages use custom view models that are essentially cut back versions of NHibernate-mapped entities.

When you have a global set of entities, reusing small pieces of entity-centric business logic is straightforward as the logic can be added to the entities. However, once we have view-specific view models, this becomes harder.

Here is a contrived example:

```
// Entity
public class Sale : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice
    {
        get { return Tax + SalePrice; }
    }
    ... more properties ...
}

// View model
public class SaleView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
}

public class Controller
{
    public Action ViewSale(Guid id)
    {
        return Session.Query<Sale>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Select(x => new SaleView
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Tax = x.Tax,
                    SalePrice = x.SalePrice
                });
    }
}
```

In this example, what strategies do you use to reuse the "TotalPrice" calculation that is currently performed in the entity?

You could make the "TotalPrice" a static method somewhere, and have it accept the tax and sale price as parameters, but this can lead to quite ugly, inflexible code, particularly as the number of properties and relationship between properties grows. You could create a seperate "TotalPriceCalculator" class, but to deal with the ViewModel it would need to accept an interface that both the entity and the view model implement. This would lead to a proliferation of duplicated code, as we now have to write out each property three times. What else can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a total price policy, which you can inject in your entity and viewmodel. The fact you inject the total price policy makes it more flexible. You could easily implement other policies. It would look some thing like this:

```
public interface ITotalPricePolicy
{
    decimal TotalPrice(decimal tax, decimal salesPrice);
}

public class TotalPricePolicy : ITotalPricePolicy
{
    public decimal TotalPrice(decimal tax, decimal salesPrice)
    {
        return tax + salesPrice;
    }
}

public class Sale : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice(ITotalPricePolicy totalPricePolicy)
    {
        return totalPricePolicy.TotalPrice(Tax, SalePrice);
    }
}

public class SaleViewModel
{
    private readonly ITotalPricePolicy _totalPricePolicy;

    public SaleViewModel(ITotalPricePolicy totalPricePolicy)
    {
        _totalPricePolicy = totalPricePolicy;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice
    {
        get { return _totalPricePolicy.TotalPrice(Tax, SalePrice); }
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITotalPricePolicy _totalPricePolicy;

    public HomeController(ITotalPricePolicy totalPricePolicy)
    {
        _totalPricePolicy = totalPricePolicy;
    }

    public Action ViewSale(Guid id)
    {
        return Session.Query<Sale>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Select(x => new SaleView(_totalPricePolicy)
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Tax = x.Tax
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, This is a known pattern called strategy or policy pattern. You can see more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern